# Spring boot YAML config for combinations of profiles

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration

From the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-change-configuration-depending-on-the-environment) on Spring boot YAML configs:

> If a YAML document contains a `spring.profiles` key, then the profiles value (a comma-separated list of profiles) is fed into the Spring `Environment.acceptsProfiles()` method. If any of those profiles is active, that document is included in the final merge...

So the `spring.profiles` key has OR logic. If you set it to `test,dev`, then the configuration is applied when the Spring profiles include either `test` or dev.

What I want is AND logic. I have multiple machine types and regions, and I want to enable some configuration on a specific combination of machine type and region, like `production,Europe`.

Is it possible to set configurations based on a combination of profiles in the YAML file?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is better suited to either a `ApplicationListener` or `EnvironmentPostProcessor`:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-boot-application.html#howto-customize-the-environment-or-application-context

For example, your `AND` logic could be:

```
@Component
public class MyListener {
    @EventListener
    public void handleContextStart(ApplicationPreparedEvent event) {
        ConfigurableEnvironment env = event.getApplicationContext().getEnvironment();

        if (env.acceptsProfiles(Profiles.of("test")) && env.acceptsProfiles(Profiles.of("test"))) {
            // Do the AND configuration here.
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can create your own `@ConfigurationProperties`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties

and in the `@PostConstruct` method, do your further customization there:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("myKey")
public class MyProperties implements EnvironmentAware {

    private Environment Environment;
    private MachineType machineType;
    private String region;

    @Override
    public setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    enum MachineType {
        MAC_OS,
        WINDOWS,
        LINUX
    }

    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        if (environment.acceptProfiles(Profiles.of("dev"))) {
            // Do some work setting other properties
            if (machineType == MachineType.WINDOWS) {
                // some other work if it's Windows
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then use `MyProperties` bean throughout your application.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to set configurations based on a combination of profiles in the YAML.

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: "production,Europe"

---

spring:
  profiles: production

one: prd one
two: prd two
three: prd three

---

spring:
  profiles: Europe

one: EU one
four: EU four
```

will give you

```
one: EU one  // <------
two: prd two
three: prd three
four: EU four
```

but if you invert the order (active: "Europe,production")

you get

```
one: prd one    // <------
two: prd two
three: prd three
four: EU four
```